# how to get whether a date is 1st,2nd etc Monday of a month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some dates in Column A, all are Monday, I need to enter a formula in column B against each record, to get which Monday of the month that is, example:

Column A-----Column B

04-Dec-17-----1

11-Dec-17-----2

18-Dec-17-----3

01-Jan-18-----1

08-Jan-18-----2

22-Jan-18-----4

29-Jan-18-----5

Comment: If they are already Monday's then doing `=INT(DAY(cell_address)/7)+1` should work.

Comment: @Enigmativity Doesn't work.. your formula is returning "2" for 07-Aug-2017, instead of 1.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `=INT((DAY(cell_address)-1)/7)+1`

Comment: perfect.. thanks @Enigmativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
=INT((DAY(cell_address)-1)/7)+1
```

It gives:

```
Date       | Week of Month
---------- | -------------
2017/12/04 | 1            
2017/12/11 | 2            
2017/12/18 | 3            
2018/01/01 | 1            
2018/01/08 | 2            
2018/01/22 | 4            
2018/01/29 | 5
```